# Hot water comes out once toilet is flushed

Tags: plumbing, hot-water

I turn on the hot water faucet and cold water comes out. This happens everywhere around the house. Once I flush the single toilet that's on the first floor and wait 1-2 mins, hot water starts pouring out of the faucet. The second floor also has this issue where I have to flush the toilet on the second floor to get hot water anywhere on that floor. The hot water would continue to stay for about 1-3 days before having to repeat the flushing process again.

Read online that many place the blame on the water heater (which doesn't seem likely but would like to hear what you think) or the house having an old plumbing structure. If so, what can I do to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: How many handles do your faucets have? (1 or 2)? have you tested this on a two handle faucet? does it behave any differently? What kind of hot water do you have? How is your water pressure? Are you on well or city water? What is the age of the house? Do you have a boiler? Do you know if you have any mixing valves?

Comment: @noybman All are two handle faucet except for the showers which are one handle and they all behave the same. Sorry but I'm not sure how to answer "what kind of hot water do you have". Not sure what's my water pressure. City water. About 1960s. Gas water heater. If I had to guess, maybe the 2 showers since whenever they are turned on (after the flushing process), the water would be scalding hot for 5-10 seconds. Afterwards, it would adjust itself to warm water.

Comment: @cutrightjim I thought that initially as well and switch the lines but still the same issue. I'll post the picture tomorrow.

Comment: I'm not sure why @cutrightjim suggested you swap lines without knowing that was the issue, also, it doesn't make sense to me or else, cold water would be hot and this wouldn't be a mystery for you. Can you turn off the water supply to the 1 handle shower(S) please? (all one handle units, turn off hot and cold to each). IN FACT.... if you could turn off **ALL** HOT/COLD everywhere, except one utility sink, (including toilets for now), and begin with that one two handle sink. Does it work? If so, begin opening valves and testing.

Comment: @noybman The way the question was worded made me think hot water was coming out of the toilet, hence my suggestion. I edited the question

Comment: If you leave a hot water tap on for say 10 minutes, is the water still cold? While doing this, can you go to the hot water tank & feel to see if the outlet pipes are getting warm?     My guess, and only a guess, is that there's a stuck mixer valve near the hot water tank which gets "unstuck" when the toilet tank draws a huge amount of cold water all at once.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I hear ya!!! I was wondering if a tub or something would do that too, but I wouldn't think a toilet is "faster" that some sinks or tubs. It doesn't sound like the OP has mixers involved unless we're talking single handle units. So Im currently thinking there is an issue on a single handle unit. (just a guess), awaiting OP response to my test steps for hopes of a clue.  @ cutrightjm I understand where you were coming from now ;)

Comment: Running the hot water for 1-2 min to get hot water at the tap isn't unusual. Try what @Carl Withoft suggested to determine if you're getting hot water out of the tank. I've seen one case where the water heater outlet plugged up from dirt, lime, rust, and a failed dip tube. Flushing the toilet could be dropping the cold supply pressure enough to cause a little backwash into the hot tank, moving a blockage somewhere.

Comment: @noybman Sorry for late response. So I cut off the water everywhere except the 2 showers as I don't know where to turn them off. Would it be behind the wall? Either way, I tested it with the bathroom faucet which is closest to the water heater and problem still exists. Same problem if I switch to the other faucets around the house.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I believe it still stays cold. I'll test again to make sure and let you know what I find

Comment: @EricSimpson That may be possible. I did replace the dip tube along with new nipples but right after the old dip tube broke inside about 5-6 months ago. Would the residue block the hot water from inside the water tank or inside the pipes? Just checked and the outlets were fine but there was a bit of residue in some of the faucets but mainly in the shower heads.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, its possible that you dont have a shutoff for those faucets. How old is your water tank by the way? Do you only have one? It's pretty odd that flushing a toilet restores your hot water. If you could take a picture of the tank and the pipes around it, and test the single handle faucets, then flush... I'm very curious if you can only get hot water by flushing....

Comment: @noybman About 2-3 years and it's only one. https://imgur.com/a/EeiuwSH
At the moment, there's hot water because of the flushing process. I will have to try it tomorrow

Comment: can you get to or see the other side of those pipes easily enough or are they all snaked behind walls? How close (or far) is the toilet(s) to the tank? Does the flush trick work if all other sinks are off, or do you have to have one or more calling for hot water for the trick to work?

Comment: At this point I'm leaning towards the same idea as @EricSimpson & Carl (just suprised at you apparent consistency in clearing it). I'd also still question single handle units, but you can "feel" water going through the pipes or the tank etc. to isolate it (looking for lack of expected flow, or flow where unexpected). You could try clearing the tank, and look at what is expunged (debris, etc)

Comment: @noybman  I was referring to a mixer valve at the heater.  Some systems allow cold water feed to "mix" with the heater hot output, reducing the final output temperature.  If that jammed, too much cold water could go straight to the pipes leading to the bathrooms.

Comment: @noybman They're snaked behind the walls sadly. I want to say about 12-15 feet. The flush trick works with and without having the faucet on, but I haven't tried running multiple at once. I did found out that when I get cold water through the hot handle, I can sense a tiny bit of hot water that is barely noticeable compared to what the cold handle gives me. Don't know if that information helps. So I guess the two possible solutions are a mixer valve gone bad somewhere around the house (at the water heater as Carl suggested) or flushing out the water tank entirely?

Comment: I had one @CarlWitthoft, and it went bad. This is still a possibilit, but we dont see it. It's usually right where the furnace, the hot water heater, or other hot sources sit (and not typically buried). Yes, please try opening a few vavles, especially if you have any two handle tubs. You could also TURN off the hot water heater valve. Do you still get pressurized water from a two handle hot? If you do, then you KNOW there is a mixer hidden.

Comment: @Alex, can you give us an update?

Comment: @noybman The problem may have been 1 of the shower's mixer valve but looking to check and see if I get hot water for at least a week (3 days going without the flushing trick) just to make sure before I post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex here (some reason I'm locked out of the original account). It happen to be the 1 of my shower's valves. I noticed that the hot and cold water inlets were connected to the valve's sides labeled "shower" and "tub". I had to detach and weld the valve back to where the "shower" points up and "tub" points down. I also replaced the plastic cartridge where the shower handle would be placed just in case. With that, I now get hot water 24/7 without having to flush a toilet beforehand. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Glad it panned out in the long run. This was one of those ones that raise an eye, but there was only a few things it could be. Congrats!!!!!